# Can I use my smartphone as a WiFi network adapter?

Tags: wi-fi, internet

I have this PC that doesn't support wiFi and I have to use usb tethering. 
But I want to see if I can project my phone's WiFi onto the computer, so it can see all the available wireless networks, whilst its still connected to USB.

I don't know how much difference this would be considering, even if I projected my wiFi on to a computer, so it can see available networks (just like a usb wireless adapter, you see these days - except using a phone) but still very much connected to a USB. So I'm not sure what the difference between this and USB/WiFi tethering, but I'd imagine it would be faster.

Edit: I actually want to be able to connect to a wiFi and see other available connections, using my phone and USB. This is to compensate for the fact that my computer doesn't support wiFi and hardware require for it.

USB network adaptors are a very good example, of what I'm trying to want to do, except with a phone.

Comment: Why do you want to see the list of networks using PC? Can't you operate the phone for some reason manually?

Comment: No, please re-read my question.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to project the Wi-Fi interface on your PC (perhaps a hack may do, but that's a different matter), but you can use ADB commands to list Wi-FI networks available, and you can even select a Wi-Fi using the commands. However, you would still need USB tethering to access the internet since as I said, Wi-Fi interface won't be available to the PC. // Other option is to use a screen-sharing program to control  the phone, but that's I think you don't want.

Comment: Hmm I see. I'll try Digvijay's method and I'll get back to you on that. But I don't see how a screen-share to control my phone would be applicable to my situation? But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have asked [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219973/packet-forwarding-between-usb-tethering-and-wifi-on-android/219978#219978). I couldn't get access to PC connected via USB (USB Tethering) from PC connected via WiFi (Mobile HotSpot). Solution was add routing for USB Tethering net on second PC.

```
$ sudo ip route add 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.43.224 dev wlp5s0
```

Here 192.168.42.0/24 is USB Tethering net, 192.168.43.224 is IP of Mobile HotSpot, wlp5s0 is WiFi interface of PC (Linux). (In my question I had two Android devices, so maybe this step is optional, I haven't checked).

Second, you should flush all the chains in ip table on Android device, e.g through [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en_us). Assumed that device is rooted:

```
$ su
# iptables -F
```

Comment: This way you'll have to add route on every device connected to WiFi hotspot or USB tethering network so that it can access devices on other network. A simple approach is to use Proxy-ARP on the device(s) used to create tethered networks. But it requires a rooted phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all available networks on the PC over your phone, I can think only one solution. 
Phone on screen. Connect your phone to PC, and all the function will be available on your PC desktop screen. Any function can be used by mouse.
Application Phone on Screen is official LG's software, but you can search on Google Play similar apps.

**EDIT 2#**
Small tutorial on

"**How to use Android device as Network adapter**".

*This is alternative way, not the direct solution!*

Small note, I have tested this on LG Flex device, and it works, plus the software is called "Phone on Screen" and it's LG's software for the same purpose as it says.

1. Download "On screen Phone" from [this link](http://lg-on-screen-phone.en.lo4d.com/) or from LG's official page and install it.
2. Since this software is already installed on LG android devices (I think only newer) there is no need to download it.
3. Connect your device to your PC. And select *tethering mode*.
4. Start "LG On Screen Phone" software who you downloaded it from internet. (By this I mean start the PC software not the actual app on android device)
5. Connect your device with cable to your PC
6. Follow the wizard who will guide you easy trough the configuration part.
7. After you have been connected to your device you'll screen the screen and controls of your device on the PC screen.
8. Now enjoy your WiFi on your Phone and your PC.

The proof of my test is this image: [image: this image]

**One note!** There are possibilities that there would pop up some error while running configuration. The error is result of selecting tethering mode over *Lg software mode*, and when this happens just click "Next" a couple of times just so it could reconnect again to your device.

**P.S** There is a feature to connect Phone and PC with Bluetooth, if someone has installed Bluetooth adapter on PC, please try and comment the result, I'll add it to this small tutorial.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I actually want to be able to connect to a wiFi and see other available connections, using my phone and USB. This is to compensate for the fact that my computer doesn't support wiFi and doesn't have the hardware for. USB network adaptors are a very good example, of what I'm trying to want to do, except with a phone.

Comment: As sad, you'll still be able to use the phone the same way + on the PC.
You'll still be able to connect to WiFi networks and view them on your phone and your PC.
Basically you'll control your phone normally + on PC.

Comment: Would you go over in detail on how to do this and maybe screenshots? It would be very much appreciated.