# Packet forwarding between USB Tethering and Wifi on Android

Tags: linux, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering

I have Toshiba **notebook** with embedded wifi adapter 2.4Ghz, **desktop** without embedded wifi adapter and Samsung Galaxy **smartphone** with **Mobile HotSpot** feature also on 2.4Ghz. Smartphone is connected to Internet through mobile operator. I need provide internet access for notebook and desktop through smartphone and combine them in network, so I will be able to ping notebook from desktop and vice versa.

I have bought TP-Link Archer T1U usb wifi adapter for my desktop and found that it supports only 5Ghz bandwidth. Yeah.. shit happens. But also I have old **rooted** Samsung Galaxy SM-T211 **tablet** with **USB Tethering** feature. So I   switch on Mobile HotSpot on smartphone and connect notebook to smartphone through wifi. Then I connect tablet to smartphone also through wifi. Finally I switch on USB Tethering feature on tablet and connect desktop to it through usb cable. Network schema is shown below.
[image]
All devices have internet access. Seems good, except **I can't ping desktop(192.168.42.56) from notebook(192.168.43.24)**.

*Forgot to mention, I use ArchLinux on both desktop and notebook.*

Comment: There's is a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/116447/218526) and I was thinking about answering that for quite some time. It's good that you have come up with a well explained solution. I suggest you move the answer part from this question to an answer to that question, and leave only the question part here (it's a Q/A site).

Comment: yeah, it has sense. What if I divide Q and A parts here and post link to this question in thread you mentioned?

Comment: duplicate questions are discouraged and highly likely to be closed. So better answer to previously existing question.

Comment: @Irfan Latif, ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

First, I add routing for 192.168.52.0/24 net via 192.168.53.224(tablet) on notebook:

```
$ sudo ip route add 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.43.224 dev wlp5s0
```

Second, flush all the chains in ip table on tablet through [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en_us). Tablet is rooted, so it is not a big problem:

```
$ su
# iptables -F
```

That is all. Now notebook can ping desktop and vice versa.