# Connect PC with USB modem to device on WiFi hotspot

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering

I am trying to connect my Oculus Quest 2, which is connected to my phone's WiFi hotspot, to a PC, which is connected to the same phone using USB tethering (USB modem). What I found out was that they get assigned different subnetworks, the one on the WiFi hotspot gets **192.168.43.x**, while PC gets **192.168.42.x**. They also get different gateways and DNS servers.

Now, I've found this answer right here ([Packet forwarding between USB Tethering and Wifi on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219973/packet-forwarding-between-usb-tethering-and-wifi-on-android)), which shares similar problem to mine, except the device is rooted. I am really not sure if this is the dealbreaker, so I'm asking general directions. Is there a way to do it without root?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this without root. If you want to place Oculus and PC in the same network you better buy a cheap Wifi stick for the PC and let the PC open a hotspot. A hotspot is easy to install e.g. on Windows (build into Windows) or Linux.

Comment: Alright, @Robert, thank you! Well, might as well order a good router for this, since 5Ghz would be crucial..